# How would I make a certain option for <select> the default upon each refresh?

Tags: html, selection

If I have

```
<select name="visibility">
    <option value="private">private</option>
    <option value="public">private</option>
    <option value="hidden">private</option>
</select>
```

How would I make the hidden option the default?

I tried

```
    <option value="hidden" selected>hidden</option>
```

But if I choose another option and then refresh, it gets replaced with that other value. How would I make it default, regardless of refresh?

Comment: how are you refreshing? If you reload the page, the box should go back to hidden (as it is marked as selected).  unless the browser is doing something and phsyically reloading/parsing the page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your block should work fine on Chrome and IE.
however Firefox is saving your drop menu and its an old bug.
here how you fix it: add **autocomplete="off"** to your select tag
like this:

```
<select name="visibility" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="private">1</option>
    <option value="public">2</option>
    <option value="hidden" selected>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use local storage to store the selected value and on reload your check for that item and add the selected attribute

http://jsfiddle.net/d948fL09/4/

```
if( typeof localStorage.visibility !== "undefined" ){
  $('select').find($('option[value="' + localStorage.visibility  + '"]').attr('selected', true))
}

$('select').on('change', function(){
  localStorage.visibility=$(this).val();
    console.log(localStorage.visibility)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `selected="selected"` and `autocomplete="off"` attribute like so:

```
<select name="visibility" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="private">private</option>
    <option value="public">private</option>
    <option value="hidden" selected="selected">private</option>
</select>
```

This works as you want it to, no matter how often you reload the page.